# Pass array of structs from c++ to swift

Tags: c++, ios, swift

I am trying to return array of structs from c++ code to swift code.

Swift code:

```
struct CPoint {
    let x: CDouble
    let y: CDouble
}

struct CStruct {
    let p1: CPoint
    let d: CDouble
    let p2: CPoint
    let i: CInt
}

func get_structs() {

    let cnt = ... //Getting size from c++ code
    var buf = [CStruct](count: cnt, repeatedValue: CStruct(p1: CPoint(x: 0, y: 0), d: 0, p2: CPoint(x: 0, y: 0), i: 0))
    let addr = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: &buf, count: buf.count).baseAddress
    get_structs_c(addr)

    for cstruct in buf {
        //First cstruct is OK. Next are corrupted.
    }
}
```

C++ code:

```
typedef struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
}

typedef struct Struct {
    Point p1;
    double d;
    Point p2;
    int i;
}

void get_structs_c(void *buf) {
    Struct * structs = (Struct *) buf;
    const std::vector<const Struct *> vec = ... // getting values no matter from where
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        const Struct * s = vec.at(i);
        structs[i] = Struct{ s->p1, s->d, s->p2, s->i};
    }
}
```

Code is straightforward, however as a result corrupted values are saved to `buf`.

BUT, if I remove `i` field from `CStruct` and `Struct`, then it will return correct values, or if I change type of `i` from `CInt` and `int` to `CDouble` and `Double`, then will also return correct values. So, probably, some problems with `int` bridging.

I checked size of `CStruct` and `Struct` and it appeared to be the same 44 bytes.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

**UPD 1:** It works correctly only when size of struct is proportional to 8 bytes.

**UPD 2:** I checked memory addressing and found out that swift's `sizeof` tells that

```
struct CStruct {
    let p1: CPoint
    let d: CDouble
    let p2: CPoint
    let i: CInt
}
```

has size of **44** bytes, BUT &struct[1] - &struct[0] = **48**!

If reorder structure fields in a worse way:

```
struct CStruct {
    let i: CInt
    let p1: CPoint
    let d: CDouble
    let p2: CPoint
}
```

Then it automatically aligns, `sizeof` gives size of 48 and it works correctly.

Is such default incompatibility normal?

Answer (score 1):

Your `get_structs_c` function is inherently dangerous, because you do not pass in the size of the buffer, and thus this is a buffer overflow vulnerability! What you really need is a signature like this:

```
 struct StructList {
    Struct* items;
    size_t size;
 };

 StructList* CreateAndTransferOwnershipFromC();
```

Or:

```
 size_t CopyFromC(Struct* output_buffer, size_t buffer_size);
```

What's most likely happening here is that there is a size mismatch between your C++ and Swift version, where some of the buffer isn't being filled or you are overruning the buffer.

Failing that, you could be encountering an [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) issue. A safer (but perhaps less efficient) solution here would be to serialize/deserialize your data in a binary-encoded string such as with [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) that can more easily guarantee binary compatibility on both ends. Otherwise, you'll probably need to use one of the [GCC compiler directives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) for alignment / packing to ensure it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for advice, using this just for testing. But number of structs in swift array is same as number of structs in c++ code and `sizeof` gives same size of structs, and how to explain the fact, that everything is working correctly with doubles?
Also would not I get overflow error in that case? I just get messed up values.

Comment: This is still a pretty dangerous thing you're doing (so I'd strongly suggest communicating buffer size explicitly), but it could be a packing/alignment issue... updated answer.